# Firebase - Lazy Loading List of Data

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, firebase

I have a requirement where I want to display say the first 10 entries in a list and once the user scrolls down I would like to append the next 10 entries. I am currently using Angularfire and all the documentation specifies that I should not do array operations on a $FirebaseArray:

> This array should not be directly manipulated. Methods like splice(), push(), pop(), and unshift() will cause the data to become out of sync with server.

So my options are to load the next 10 entries and:

- Use $add(), which would write them to the server again (think this could cause some nasty recursion)
- Use concat, in which case my data will get out of sync with the server
- Get the list again but adjust the limit to be 20, which I think would cause all the data to be reloaded defeating the purpose of lazy loading.

Here is the code that initially loads the list (based on the Angularfire seed app):

```
var lastKey = null;
var firstKey = null;
$scope.messages = fbutil.syncArray(userMessages,{'limit':10});
$scope.messages.$loaded(function(data){
  lastKey = data.$keyAt(data.length-1);
  firstKey = data.$keyAt(0);
});
```

And here is the code that is triggered when the user scrolls down:

```
$document.on('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
   var newMessages = fbutil.syncArray(messagePath,{'limit':10,'startAt':lastKey});
   newMessages.$loaded(function(data){
      lastKey = data.$keyAt(data.length-1);
      firstKey = data.$keyAt(0);
      $scope.messages.concat(newMessages);// this is probably a bad idea
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you continue reading on the documentation page for AngularFire (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html), you'll see: "Instead, AngularFire provides a set of methods compatable with manipulating synchronized arrays: $add(), $save(), and $remove()." So that's how you add/remove items. But implementing a infinite scrolling list is not documented like that. Did you already make a start on implementing it?

Comment: Also have a look at this blog post from Kato: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#paginate. It demonstrates how to do pagination, which is essentially how you intend to implement load-on-demand .

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I have previously looked at the pagination example from Kato, however the use case is slightly different. In pagination you replace the existing list with a new list. What I need to do is to append the current list with the next 10 entries. however if I used $add() the next 10 entries will be appended to the current list locally and on the server, and if I use concat() then I risk the data getting out of sync with the server.

Comment: The best answer is to just create a new AngularFire reference for now. We'll be working on some pretty spiffy client-side paging tools (they'll knock your socks off) which are compatible with AngularFire in the next month or two.

Comment: Thanks Kato, I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kato's comment the following is the best solution given the current API.

```
var limit= 10;
$scope.messages = fbutil.syncArray(messagePath,{'limit':limit});
```

And the scroll trigger

```
$document.on('scroll', function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
   limit += 10;
   $scope.messages = fbutil.syncArray(messagePath,{'limit':limit});
 }
});
```